# Possible bug in youtube most popular video chart retrieval?

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Just trying to see if people here have come across and have been stumped by this before or if this actually is expected behavior.

The v3 youtube api call to retrieve the most popular content by region and category does not seem to return videos that actually belong to that category.

For example, take this request:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=snippet%2CcontentDetails%2Cstatistics&chart=mostPopular&maxResults=50&regionCode=US&videoCategoryId=2&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

I ask for `videoCategoryId =2` (Autos & Vehicles), however, the results I retrieve are actually not tagged with that Category when I check that video on youtube. For example, some of the results I get:

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y00PcyOHUwU 

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M8IBQI0R5NI

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=G2g9Juufntc
```

Any thoughts and whether I should report this to Youtube?

Comment: if you feel there is a bug just report it google will sort it out https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/entry?template=YouTube%20(Defect%20Report)